# How to Properly Render Quad Wireframe in Three.js from OBJ Model?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I want to render the actual wireframe of OBJ meshes with Three.js. Unfortunately, Three.js does only render triangles. Thus my idea was to build a line for every edge of the model.

I was able to get it working by parsing the OBJ file and looping through its **vertices** and **faces**.

---

On the right is the normal `LineSegments` model with triangles and on the left my attempt to render the actual wireframe.

#### Code: https://codepen.io/flolu/pen/zYrexyr

[image: wireframes]

## But there are some problems with my method

#### 1. Performance

The viewport lags after adding all of the lines. This is especially bad considering, that this model isn't really big.

#### 2. Clipping

At some parts of the mesh, lines aren't rendered. Probably because the inner mesh is rendered with triangles, which causes clipping?!

[image: clipping]

#### 3. Will this work?

Since I don't have much experience working with OBJ files, I am not sure if this method will work for all meshes. And I would prefer an implementation which can also be applies to other file formats.

For example if you change line `182` from

```
const model = antler;
```

to

```
const model = test;
```

it will load another model, which doesn't work. Some edges are missing.
[image: broken wireframe]

---

It would be awesome if someone could improve the CodePen :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:**

This approach gets very poor performance because you're rendering `4370` lines independently on each frame! That many drawcalls will decimate most machines' framerate. I recommend you create one single [`LineSegments`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/LineSegments) object with all the necessary vertex pairs, instead of four-thousand individual `Line` objects. This way all lines get rendered in a single call!

**Question 2:**

You could avoid clipping by setting the material to `depthTest: false` and set the [`renderOrder`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.renderOrder) to a higher number than the white mesh so it renders last, on top of it.

**Question 3:**

I can't help you here, it depends on how your OBJ is built. I should mention, multiple questions in a single post are frowned upon in Stack Overflow because they [reduce the usefulness of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). In the future, consider breaking it up into individual questions, or you may ask in a more open-ended forum, such as https://discourse.threejs.org

Comment: Awesome, rendering on `LineSegments` object is much more performant! And you're right, I will split the other two questions into their own